# Show all users liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui, liferay-ide

I need to make a portlet which would show all registred users in liferay.

Im not asking you to write all code here, but I would aprreciate if u could present an step-by-step plan of actions, cause I really don't understand how to get info from database.

UPD:
 1. I can`t solve what should I import in java file.
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;

```
import javax.portlet.PortletException;
import javax.portlet.PortletPreferences;
import javax.portlet.RenderRequest;
import javax.portlet.RenderResponse;
import javax.transaction.SystemException;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.dao.orm.QueryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.model.User;
import com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.util.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;
public class ShowUsers extends MVCPortlet {

public void render(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException{
            Log log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(ShowUsers.class);
            List<User> users = null;
            try {
                users = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
            } catch (com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException e) {
                log.info("Exception happened");
            }
            renderRequest.setAttribute("allUsers", users );
            super.render(renderRequest, renderResponse);

     }

}
```

===================
My jsp file:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
    <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
    <%@ page import="com.liferay.portal.model.User" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %> 
    <portlet:defineObjects /> 
    <%
         List<User> thatusers = renderRequest.getAttribute("allUsers");
    %>

    <ul>
    <% for (User user : thatusers) { %>
    <li><%= user %></li>
    <% } %> 
    </ul>
```

And after this code I have strange info about all users and I need only it's name! this:

{uuid=fb7224c0-2488-45c1-97b8-5608450435a6, userId=20199, companyId=20155, createDate=2016-06-06 08:14:14.0, modifiedDate=2016-06-06 08:14:14.0, defaultUser=false, contactId=20200,

Comment: The User class import seems missing in jsp. Also the user object will give you all required attributes.You can google up on iterating list using jstl,which should likely serve your purpose.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal when I use my code I have awful info, for example:

{uuid=fb7224c0-2488-45c1-97b8-5608450435a6, userId=20199, companyId=20155, createDate=2016-06-06 08:14:14.0, modifiedDate=2016-06-06 08:14:14.0, defaultUser=false, contactId=20200, 

I've googled so much but I still don't know how to solve it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all users take a look at `UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers()`

In your portlet class you need to pass this list to the jsp you are serving:

```
public void doView(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse)
throws IOException, PortletException {
    List<User> users =  UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
    renderRequest.setAttribute("allUsers", users );
    super.doView(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

And than in your jsp iterate the allUsers list using JSTL  to get a user object.

`getUsers(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);` would retrieve all the users, instead of `QueryUtil.ALL_POS` you can specifie start and end if you need to paginate the result.

Comment: I've already heard about `UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers()`, but my question is about what to do before it? 

What method should consist this line? What should be in jsp? Should I use Service Builder? Could you please write it down more clear?

Comment: I edited my answer, as for Service Builder you dont need it as long as you're not creating services for your own table's or making references to Liferay's tables.

Comment: You're printing the user object itself instead of just the value you need, if you need to get the username you can do `<li><%= user.getScreenName() %></li>`
see: [UserModel](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/model/UserModel.html)